# How to convert array of dictionary to JSON?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, swift2

I have an array of dictionaries that I'd like to convert to JSON. My object is of type `[[String: AnyObject]]` and would like to end up with a sample like this:

```
[
  { "abc": 123, "def": "ggg", "xyz": true },
  { "abc": 456, "def": "hhh", "xyz": false },
  { "abc": 789, "def": "jjj", "xyz": true }
]
```

This is what I'm trying, but the compiler is not liking my declaration:

```
extension Array where Element == Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    var json: String {
        do { return try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self, options: []) ?? "[]" }
        catch { return "[]" }
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: so your question isn't about JSON generation but constraining Element.

Comment: `dataWithJSONObject` returns `NSData` on success, so at least you have to create a string to return.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple way to achieve that is to just extend CollectionType.

Use optional binding and downcasting, then serialize to data, then convert to string.

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element == [String:AnyObject] {
    func toJSONString(options: NSJSONWritingOptions = .PrettyPrinted) -> String {
        if let arr = self as? [[String:AnyObject]],
            let dat = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(arr, options: options),
            let str = String(data: dat, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            return str
        }
        return "[]"
    }
}

let arrayOfDictionaries: [[String:AnyObject]] = [
    ["abc":123, "def": "ggg", "xyz": true],
    ["abc":456, "def": "hhh", "xyz": false]
]

print(arrayOfDictionaries.toJSONString())
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "abc" : 123,
    "def" : "ggg",
    "xyz" : true
  },
  {
    "abc" : 456,
    "def" : "hhh",
    "xyz" : false
  }
]
```

Comment: This will solve the asker's issue, but introduce subtle bugs, like dictionaries being converted to `[]` instead of their JSON equivalent. I think the asker also seeks for type safety, which would prevent runtime issues like this.

Comment: @Cristik Good thinking. I've added a type constraint to the extension. It should be closer to what OP wanted.

Comment: I'm running into `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` errors when I create the `arrayOfDictionaries`. This may require a different question but it's making this solution not work...

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 4**:

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == [String:AnyObject] {
    func toJSONString(options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions = .prettyPrinted) -> String {
        if let arr = self as? [[String:AnyObject]],
            let dat = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arr, options: options),
            let str = String(data: dat, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            return str
        }
        return "[]"
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let arrayOfDictionaries = [
  { "abc": 123, "def": "ggg", "xyz": true },
  { "abc": 456, "def": "hhh", "xyz": false },
  { "abc": 789, "def": "jjj", "xyz": true }
]

print(arrayOfDictionaries.toJSONString())
```

Comment: return error (key: String, value: Any)' is not convertible to '[String : Any]'

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**, I had to change it to `Any` instead of `AnyObject`, building off solutions of Eric & A.G.

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == [String: Any] {
  func toJSONString(options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions = .prettyPrinted) -> String {
    if let arr = self as? [[String: Any]],
       let dat = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arr, options: options),
       let str = String(data: dat, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
      return str
    }
    return "[]"
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let arrayOfDictionaries = [
  { "abc": 123, "def": "ggg", "xyz": true },
  { "abc": 456, "def": "hhh", "xyz": false },
  { "abc": 789, "def": "jjj", "xyz": true }
]

print(arrayOfDictionaries.toJSONString())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're out of luck trying to extend `Array`, because same-type requirements are not possible when extending an entity.

What you can make is to make use of free functions:

```
func jsonify(array: [[String:AnyObject]]) { 
...
}
```

This way you'll keep the type safety you want to, with the expense of moving the function location.