# Creation of JSON array in swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift3

i want to create a json array in the below format in swift 3

```
{

"parameter" :

[ {

"key" : "paymentType",

"value" : "F"

} ]

}
```

Comment: @Ashish Bahl can you help me to create a json array

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826824/creating-json-array-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

Using [SwiftyJson](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

```
var jsonArray: JSON = ["parameter": ["key": "paymentType","value": "F"]]
```

Best I could do with the information you gave. Hardcoding values into something like this isn't usualy the best idea so I would recommend you go and try learn a bit more about SwiftyJSON which might make working with JSON a bit easier for you.