# How can I loop through json array in node?

Tags: ios, node.js, express

I want to loop through `times`, but `times` is `undefined` when debugging.

```
router.post('/something', function (req, res) {
    var times = req.body.times;
    for (i = 0; i < times.length; i++) { 
        // do something
    }
}
```

Here is what body.times looks like when debugging:

```
{"duration":3600,"startTime":540,"weekDay":0},{"duration":3600,"startTime":600,"weekDay":0},{"duration":3600,"startTime":660,"weekDay":0},{"duration":3600,"startTime":1080,"weekDay":6}:""
```

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like in VSCode debugging. Replace `spans` with `times`. (I just changed it to `times` on this question to be more clear.)
[image]

Here is the swift code:

```
var jsonArray: [[String: Any]] = [/*The array*/]
let json: [String: Any] = ["times": jsonArray]
guard let body = (try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, 
                                                     options: [])) 
else { 
    return nil 
}
```

Here is how I configure express:

```
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }))
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }))
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}))
```

Output of json:

```
 (lldb) po print(json)
 ["spans": [["weekDay": 0, "duration": 3600.0, "startTime": 540], ["weekDay": 0, "duration": 3600.0, "startTime": 600]]]
```

The headers [image]

Comment: is `body.times` really an array? it looks like you've got trailing `:""` and missing `[]`

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure. I'm guessing it's not, but I don't know why. That's the underlying problem I guess.

Comment: Your Array looks like a more like an object of objects without any key to specify the object than an Array of objects in the _spans_

Comment: Your problem is in your swift code. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39439913/7118774) for finding solution

Comment: Can you put up output of the swift code? the value of `jsonArray`

Comment: Yup, just added `json` which includes `jsonArray`

Comment: What are the headers you see in the request? If "times" is undefined it may be that bodyParser doesn't parse the json body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two parts to test in your code

1. Node js
2. Swift

1.Node js

Test your api with postment
check content type (application/json or multipart)
and verify its working

2)Check your Swift code and match with content type of server

Your data

```
{"duration":3600,"startTime":540,"weekDay":0},{"duration":3600,"startTime":600,"weekDay":0},{"duration":3600,"startTime":660,"weekDay":0},{"duration":3600,"startTime":1080,"weekDay":6}:""
```

you are iterating on object not on array
so its wont work.

Comment: My content type was incorrect. I needed to set it to `application/json`.